# Active Broadcom wifi on startup

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Using this answer [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?newreg=26d46c985db54fd882533470b16f25e3) I was able to get my Broadcom 4311 working in 16.04. However, I have to open the terminal and enter "sudo modprobe b43" every time I restart or it doesn't find any wifi sources. Where could I put this line to make it automatically run on startup?

Thanks in advance for helping a newbie.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Comment: This is wierd. If `wl` is installed, the Wi-Fi should not work because `wl` is bind to it. If it is not, the file should not be there.

Comment: Sometimes people uninstall when they should purge. I took an educated guess!

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I also updated and it still worked. Much appreciated.